# Сравнение двух таблиц

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос

Необходимо сравнить 2 таблицы, в 1-й таблице больше записей чем во 2-м, но и во второй таблице есть id-шники которые нет в первой таблице

Вообщем необходимо определить разницу вывести null показать разницу и написать в колонке типа есть различие

Comment: Чтобы задать хороший вопрос про SQL, [используйте эту инструкцию](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-sql).

Comment: Воспользуйтесь моим ответом:

table1.id = ob.esbd_id
table1 = [dbo].[ogpo_branch]
table2 = [dbo].[Филиалы Цесна Гарант$] f
table2.id = f.[Код регионального подразделения ЕСБД - ID]
И тогда запрос выглядит:

SELECT ob.esbd_id, f.[Код регионального подразделения ЕСБД - ID] from [dbo].[ogpo_branch] 
FULL OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Филиалы Цесна Гарант$] f ON ob.esbd_id  = f.[Код регионального подразделения ЕСБД - ID]  
WHERE ob.esbd_id IS NULL OR f.[Код регионального подразделения ЕСБД - ID] IS NULL;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```sql
SELECT table1.id, table2.id from table1 
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id  
WHERE table1.id IS NULL OR table2.id IS NULL;
```

Результатом запроса будет таблица содержащая в первой колонке id записей которые есть только в первой таблице, во второй - id записей которые есть только во второй таблице.